# Is DDD logic can only be use in event triggered? like POST,PUT,DELETE? and when retrieving (GET) no need to use DDD logic?

Tags: domain-driven-design

DDD can only be use in event triggered? like POST,PUT,DELETE? I try to search on the internet for how many months, I can only see that they use DDD logic when the user form is submitted. But when retrieving the data (GET) there is no logic involve, they just query it and display in the U.I. Is that acceptable if I store computed total in the database or retrieve the data and compute it?

. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is designed with DDD for a specific bounded context, then it SHOULD be the only authoritative application for that context. It means it SHOULD be the only one able to update the that context's state. It means every changes to that context SHOULD go through this application domain layer.

If every change to this context is done by your application, and if you enforce all domain rules when updating your context state, then your context state CANNOT be persisted in an invalid state. In that situation, you don't need to enforce domain rules when reading the context's state, as this was already done when updating it.

In conclusion :

**You MAY bypass your domain logic validation when reading/querying your application state IF you prevent other components from violating your authority over that context.**